# Sorting Lists by Repetitions in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that contains multiple repeated items. I'm trying to sort the list by giving items with the most repetitions priority.

So it would turn this

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd']
```

into this

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [k for k,v in Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd']).most_common() for i in xrange(v)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

This is possibly easier to follow

```
>>> counter = Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd'])
>>> sorted(counter.elements(), key=counter.get, reverse=True)
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
d = {}
for a in l:
    d[a] += d.setdefault(a,0)

l.sort(key = lambda k: (d[k],k), reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[v for (v, c) in sorted(((x, list(y)) for (x, y) in
  itertools.groupby(sorted(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd']))),
  key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True) for z in c]
```

**EDIT:**

Now with `sum()`!

```
sum((c for (v, c) in sorted(((x, list(y)) for (x, y) in
  itertools.groupby(sorted(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd']))),
  key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)), [])
```

Comment: Unfortunately sum with lists has quadratic performance, so should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd']
sorted_list = [item for item in sorted(l, key=lambda x: l.count(x), reverse=True)]
```

While this is a simple solution, mind the complexity of counting every element when using large lists.

Comment: For a large list calling count constantly will not be very efficient

Comment: Indeed, I also felt the need to add a comment about complexity.

Comment: Why not just `sorted(l, key=lambda x: l.count(x), reverse=True)`?

Comment: I agree with Johnsyweb; the list comprehension is redundant.

Comment: Why not just `sorted(l, key=l.count, reverse=True)`? Because all these answers are O(N^2)

Comment: @gnibbler: I wasn't trying to address the time complexity (other answers and comments have done that). I was questioning the redundant list comprehension.